# Run scripts on websites using DevTools

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

If I'm on a site, on YouTube for example, how do I run a script using DevTools (ctrl + shift + i) to ... keep the title of a video moving for example? Or anything like that.

When I'm on youtube I can use DevTools to change a title of a video, delete the "play" button or change the color of something, and continue on the page without problems. I want to run a script (something simple), I wrote:

```
<script> 
   function a () {alert ("test)} </script>
```

and created a button: 
`<button id =" but1 "type =" button "onclick =" a()> button </button>` when I clicked, nothing happened.When I created the button, it appeared immediately, but the script is never "created".
**How can I add a script to sites that are not mine using DevTools?**

Comment: Is it important that you use DevTools to run the script?

Comment: Yesss, its important @U-ways

Comment: What about using a Chrome extension to run the script?

Comment: ? Could you give me more information? Thanks @U-ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/25/gotchas-with-dynamically-adding-script-tags-to-html you can find a way to asynchronously add and execute javascript.
Specifically, you can write the following code in the console:

```
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
var inlineScript = document.createTextNode("function a() {alert('test');}");
newScript.appendChild(inlineScript); 
document.body.appendChild(newScript);
```

Hope it helps